# Gitflow with Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I researched this topic quite a bit but was not able so far to find an answer.

We deployed a GitLab-CE appliance and are very happy with the decision so far.
We also follow and use the gitflow principles.

On thing which bothers me and which I would like to find a solution to is that
with gitflow, when a developer finishes a feature/bugfix/... with:

```
git flow feature finish foo
```

AFAIK git flow will merge the foo branch to develop. Which wont help when using GitLab for the Team.

Because on origin we currently protect master and develop. So it is not allowed to push to these branches.

Is there a way to alter the gitflow configuration or another kind of solution to combine gitflow with GitLab?

We als currently try to figure out which solution is the best to get CI up and going. When this is done, merges to develop could be allowed again.

Any links, tutorials and so on would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git flow feature publish <branch>` to publish the feature branch to the remote repository without having to merge it with `feature finish`.

Then do your merge request on Gitlab as usual.

Comment: I was inclined to mark your answer as accepted. However, as useful as it is, it also doesn't quite 'finish' the branch. Nevertheless it is a useful tip. Could be combined with an some alias to publish to remote and afterwards remove the branch in question.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution would be to, instead of using the `feature finish` command, push the feature branch and make a merge request on GitLab. This will allow others to inspect the changes and merge them when everything is okay. The merging can be done locally using `feature finish` by the repository administrator, or using the online interface, which will do the same thing.

This will preserve Git Flow, as the merging pattern will be the same. The loose local feature branch can, after the merge, be removed, using either `branch -d` or `feature finish`.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped for a more convenient way. This is the way we do it right now and it does the job.